# What need do with 'ssh:Connection refused'?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, ssh

I try install SFTP with [this](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/) guide on Ubuntu Server.

When I do step 9:

```
 sudo service ssh restart
```

My ssh connection was dropped down and when I want open new connect I get:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

So what is this? And what I can if I have not another access to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the guide you will see this step that adds

/usr/sbin/nologin

This actually prevents shell/terminal access. If you have changed your current username to a sftp only user account then you cannot use terminal ssh to login.

To clarify, unless you have another account that have ssh access you are not able to access remotely. Unless you are using service like DO which have local terminal access and you can login with root.

Comment: DO = digital ocean?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, not sure whether I was allow to type that here so I wrote the short form.

Comment: I remember, what skip step 2-6. Do step 1 and starting with 'sudo apt-get install openssl-server'. What else could it be?

Comment: I will skip step 10 if I still want ssh login.